# using cache make vector fast or what?

Tags: c++, vector, dynamic-memory-allocation, allocation

i have question about c++ vector. i test **1000000** **push_back** on vector (int) type and it's done in only 
 **4 miliseconds**

```
vector <int> Test;
    auto start_t = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) Test.push_back(i);
    cout << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start_t).count() << " milliseconds\n" << endl;
```

but if i made my own array engine, it's took about 3 min to do this action even i set allocation to allocating size like this (count * 2) (for each allocation time)

```
template <typename T>
class Array {

private:

    T * storage_;

    int alloc_ = 0;
    int count_ = 0;
    int all_ = 0;
public:

    Array() = default;
    ~Array() { delete[] storage_; }

    void Set(const T & __t) {

        if(count_ + 1 >= alloc_) {

            T * temp = new T[count_ * 2 + 4];
            if(count_ > 0) for (int i = 0; i < count_; i++) temp[i] = storage_[i];
            delete[] storage_;
            storage_ = temp;
            all_++;
        }
        storage_[count_++] = __t;
    }

    int all() { return all_; }
    int count() { return count_; }
};
```

... how possible this speed? is it cache? because i don't belive it to be a c++ optimization because what ever done on optimization, it's can not make vector fast like this ... i think it's completly cache or something else which detect we have 1000000 times push back so allocating 1000000 size at the start and do process ... is it true or something else?

Comment: Or what, I'd say

Comment: You should consider using [std::vector::reserve](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) and you need to read documentation of C++ [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container). BTW, several C++ standard libraries are free software (packaged in C++ compilers like [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) so you can study their implementation and source code.

Comment: `__t` is UB.͏͏͏͏͏͏

Answer (score 2):

Your reallocation logic is broken because it does not set `alloc_`. Thus it reallocates every single time. And your `all_` member is meaningless. It appears that you somehow confused those two variables.

Comment: no all_ is only for myself to check how many reallocation done ... source set to use alloc_ (to get allocated size)

Comment: Ah, then you should have actually checked that variable and noticed how it reallocates every time you call `Set`. This is why abbreviations are bad, by the way. You should have called that variable `allocations_`.